# Pyvmomi supported types

Tags: python, pyvmomi, vmware-sdk

**Background**

I am trying to extract all of the information from vmware that I can via its API and pyvmomi.

I noticed from pyvmomi examples that this is how to get all of the vms on a vsphere instance:

```
import yaml
from pyVmomi import vim
from pyVim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect, SmartConnectNoSSL
si = SmartConnectNoSSL(host=vserver, user=user, pwd=password, port=port)
container = si.RetrieveContent().viewManager.CreateContainerView(si.RetrieveContent().rootFolder, [vim.VirtualMachine], True)
```

Now, I am hoping to loop through a list of all the extractable resources types (like vim.VirtualMachine, vim.ResourcePool, etc)

But, I cannot find this list.

**Question:** What is this list?

Is there some way to find this list from the pyvmomi module?

**More info**

I have used this link: https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22/fa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc/doc/index.html to find a list of all the managed objects on vmware, but many do not seem to be supported. And, I do not kn ow if this list contains every supported pyVmomi type. Only these resources:

```
ResourcePool
VirtualApp
Datacenter
VirtualMachine
Datastore
Network
ClusterComputeResource
OpaqueNetwork
HostSystem
DistributedVirtualPortgroup
ManagedEntity
ComputeResource
VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch
StoragePod
Folder
DistributedVirtualSwitch
```

Do not error out on the `container =` code. For instance vim.Alarm is not supported in the `RetrieveContent` call but it does exist as part of vim.

The error is:

```
container = si.RetrieveContent().viewManager.CreateContainerView(si.RetrieveContent().rootFolder, [vim.Alarm], True)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/vmware-extract/vmware-extract-0.1.0/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVmomi/VmomiSupport.py", line 706, in <lambda>
    self.f(*(self.args + (obj,) + args), **kwargs)
  File "/root/vmware-extract/vmware-extract-0.1.0/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVmomi/VmomiSupport.py", line 512, in _InvokeMethod
    return self._stub.InvokeMethod(self, info, args)
  File "/root/vmware-extract/vmware-extract-0.1.0/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyVmomi/SoapAdapter.py", line 1374, in InvokeMethod
    raise obj # pylint: disable-msg=E0702
pyVmomi.VmomiSupport.InvalidArgument: (vmodl.fault.InvalidArgument) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
   msg = 'A specified parameter was not correct: type',
   faultCause = <unset>,
   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) [],
   invalidProperty = u'type'
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
from pyVmomi import vim
vim.Alarm
dir(vim) 
vim.VirtualMachine
dir(vim)
```

returns

```
['Alarm','__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'fault', 'name']
['Alarm', 'VirtualMachine', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'name']
```

`dir(vim)` will not list any resource type unless I first know it and type vim.resourceTypeNameHere

But, even if it does show up in the list, the `RetrieveContent()` line still errors on some of the resourceTypes. For instance Alarm errors as can be seen above.

Comment: try `dir(vim)`, that should list out the attributes and objects associated with that module

Comment: @C.Nivs see Edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

vim.VirtualMachine  only a list ['vm01','vm02',...]

try this

```
def get_obj(content, vimtype, name=None):
    '''
    return list 
    '''
    container = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(content.rootFolder, vimtype, True)
    obj = [ view for view in container.view]
    return obj

vm_objs = get_obj(content, [vim.VirtualMachine])
for vm in vm_objs:
    print(dir(vm))
```